# Message is not printed Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

When the user didn't chose any option, the code going into else, in `if_button_ispressed` function, and then I want to print an error message on the screen. I think I did all correct but the message is not shown on the screen.

```
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk
import ShareScreen
import Menu_WatchAnothersScreen

def if_button_is_pressed(): 
    global user_selection, mGui
    if(user_selection.get() == 1): # if the user want to share his screen
        mGui.destroy()
        ShareScreen.run()
        #menu()
    if(user_selection.get() == 2): # if the user want to watch another`s screen
        mGui.destroy()
        Menu_WatchAnothersScreen.run()
        #menu()
    else: # if the user didn`t chose any option  <--------------- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        error_message = "Please select one of the options" #<--------------- HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        error_label = Label(mGui, textvariable=error_message).pack(anchor=CENTER) # prints error message <--------------- HERE IS MY PROBLEM


def close(): # close the window
    exit()

def menu():

    global user_selection,mGui

    mGui = Tk()
    user_selection = IntVar()

    menubar = Menu(mGui)  # menu

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  # menu works
    filemenu.add_command(label="Close", command=close)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)

    mGui.geometry('450x300+500+300')
    mGui.title('Nir`s ScreenShare') # top of window

    canvas = Canvas(mGui, width=500, height=150)
    canvas.pack(pady = 10)
    pilImage = Image.open("logo5.png") 
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)# puts ScreenirShare`s logo on the menu
    imagesprite = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor="nw")
    Radiobutton(mGui, text="Share My Screen             ", variable=user_selection, value=1).pack(anchor=CENTER) # 1 -  FIRST OPTION - Share My Screen
    Radiobutton(mGui, text="Watch Another`s Screen", variable=user_selection, value=2).pack(anchor=CENTER, pady = 7.5)# 2- SECOND OPTION - Watch Another`s Screen



    start_button = Button(mGui, text='Start', command=if_button_is_pressed).pack()  # Start Button


    mGui.config(menu=menubar)  # menu helper

    mGui.mainloop()


menu()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use plain string, you should use `text` option of label not `textvariable`.

```
Label(mGui, text=error_message)
```

If you want to use textvariable, you need [StringVar, IntVar](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) etc.

Also, packing on same line returns `None`, so you should pack after you create it if you want to use it again later.

```
error_label = Label(mGui, textvariable=error_message)
error_label.pack(anchor=CENTER)
```